# Correct use of NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I've been following the apple docs as well as some code on here and I can't seem to get NSDateComponents to work correctly.

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:dateValue];
[calendar release];
```

dateValue is some date, I only care about the time of it, and the time is 8:00AM.  When I check what components is after this, Hour and Minute are both nil.

I also tried inserting this, because I read that you needed to (although not every example has this):

```
[components setCalendar:calendar];
```

Answer (score 2):

That code will work. Maybe it's because you're trying to access the hour and minute incorrectly. I did this and got the current hour and minute in the Console window:

```
NSDate *dateValue = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:dateValue];
NSLog(@"hour: %d, minute: %d", [components hour], [components minute]);
[calendar release];
```

`-hour` and `-minute` return plain integers, not NSNumber objects.

From ios8 onwards above class constant is deprecated, use below code:

```
NSDate *dateValue = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:dateValue];
NSLog(@"hour: %ld, minute: %d", (long)[components hour], [components minute]);
```

Comment: It actually had to do with the calendar.  I think I just kept checking with the same time over and over and it so happened that my calendar is -8 timezone I believe, so I was getting 0.